# Responsive Dropdown Navigation Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I m new to Jquery.
I m trying to build responsive website, so started with Navigation Part.
i written some sort of code for the navigation and it works good and navigation having nested items.But the problem is that whenever the window is resized , navigation is collapsed to 'Menu' nav-button, when i click on nav-item it overlapping other nav-items.
Also the selected nav-item is not getting closed, whenever i select different nav-item.

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8h8q7y8z/

Here is My Code

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar">
    <span class="nav-btn"></span>
    <div class="container">

        <div id="brand">
            <img src="Img/logo1.png" class="visible" />
            <img src="Img/smallLogo.png" class="hidden" />
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="Img/home2.png" height="20" /></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">HOTEL</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TOURS</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">EUROPE MAIL</a><img src="Img/arrowDown.png" />
                    <ul class="dditems">
                        <li><a href="EuropeRail.html">Europe Rail</a></li>
                        <li><a href="EuropeRailWorld.html">Europe Rail World</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">VACATIONS</a><img src="Img/arrowDown.png" />
                    <ul class="dditems">
                        <li><a href="Vocation.html">Cheap Caribbean</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Hurtigruten.html">Hurtigruten</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Contiki.html">Contiki</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Sandals.html">Sandals</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">HOME RENTALS</a><img src="Img/arrowDown.png" />
                    <ul class="dditems">
                        <li><a href="HomeRental.html">Vacation Home Rentals</a></li>
                        <li><a href="HomeExchange.html">Home For Exchange</a></li>
                        <li><a href="HomeAway.html">Home Away Europe</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">CRUISE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">INSURANCE</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">ATTRACTION</a><img src="Img/arrowDown.png" />
                    <ul class="dditems">
                        <li><a href="CityPass.html">City Pass</a></li>
                        <li><a href="StarlineTours.html">Starline Tours</a></li>
                        <li><a href="DublinPass.html">Dublin Pass</a></li>
                        <li><a href="NewyorkPass.html">New york Pass</a></li>
                        <li><a href="TrustedTours.html">Trusted Tours</a></li>
                        <li><a href="PariscityVision.html">Paris city Vision</a></li>
                        <li><a href="LondonPass.html">London Pass</a></li>
                        <li><a href="GrayLine.html">Gray Line</a></li>
                        <li><a href="SmartDestinations.html">Smart Destinations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="CityExperts.html">City Experts NY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Conciergerie.html">Conciergerie</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Isango.html">isango</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 html {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }

    * {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .container {
        padding-right: 25px;
        padding-left: 100px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }


    .navbar {
        background: #333333;
        height: 50px;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #brand {
        float: left;
        padding-right: 30px;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }

    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }

    .visible {
        display: block;
    }

    nav {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

        nav ul {
            float: left;
            line-height: 50px;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            position: relative;
        }

            nav ul li {
                display: inline-block;
                list-style-type: none;
            }

                nav ul li a {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    padding: 10px;
                    color: #9d9d9d;
                    font-size: 14px;
                }

                nav ul li:hover {
                    background-color: #333;
                }

                nav ul li a:hover {
                    color: #fff;
                }

                nav ul li:hover ul {
                    display: block;
                }

            nav ul ul {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: #333;
                min-width: 150px;
            }

                nav ul ul li {
                    display: block;
                    line-height: 25px;
                    text-align: left;
                }

    .dropdown img {
        display: none;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 985px) {

        .container {
            padding-left: 10px;
        }

        .nav-btn {
            position: relative;
            float: right;
            padding: 4px 5px;
            margin-top: 12px;
            margin-right: 15px;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

            .nav-btn:hover {
                color: #9d9d9d;
                background-color: #fff;
            }

            .nav-btn:before {
                content: "Menu";
            }

        .hidden {
            display: block;
        }

        .visible {
            display: none;
        }

        nav {
            float: right;
            display: none;
            background-color: #fff;
        }


            nav ul {
                text-align: left;
                float: right;
                line-height: 25px;
                padding: 5px;
            }

                nav ul li {
                    display: block;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #968a8a;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }

                    nav ul li:hover {
                        background-color: #968a8a;
                    }

                    nav ul li a {
                        color: rgb(0,0,0);
                    }

                    nav ul li:hover ul {
                        display: none;
                    }


        .dropdown img {
            display: block;
            float: right;
            margin-top: 4px;
            margin-right: 4px;
        }

        ul .dditems {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #968a8a;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1094px) {
        .container {
            padding-left: 10px;
        }

        #brand {
            padding-right: 10px;
        }


        /*.hidden {
            display: block;
        }

        .visible {
            display: none;
        }*/
    }
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("span.nav-btn").click(function () {
            $("nav").slideToggle();
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
        $(".dropdown").click(function () {
            $(this).children(".dditems").slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

Comment: When you create a fiddle, make sure you include JQuery if it's needed (top left of fiddle window) - what do you expect to happen? What solution are you looking for? You need to ask a question to get an answer

Comment: yes , nw updated my fiddle, PLz take take look and help me, Click on links in navigation and see the dropdown overlapping with others,  m not gttng how to remove it

Comment: What would you like to happen? There's still no question

Comment: i dont want overlapping of Navigation elements For ex: when i click on 'EUROPE MAIL' it shows it's sub-elements over the main elements i.e,VACATIONS and HOME RENTALS are hiding so, i dont want such thnings

Comment: Like this i want ...  resize window and see http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Lightweight-Responsive-jQuery-Dropdown-Menu-Plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to this - All I've done is change `absolute` position to `relative` and given the menu a fixed width, which you can of course change:

```
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
  background: #333333;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#brand {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #9d9d9d;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #333;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #333;
                    /*min-width: 150px;*/;
}

nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown img {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 985px) {

  .container {
    padding-left: 10px;
  }

  .nav-btn {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding: 4px 5px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .nav-btn:hover {
    color: #9d9d9d;
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  .nav-btn:before {
    content: "Menu";
  }

  .hidden {
    display: block;
  }

  .visible {
    display: none;
  }

  nav {
    float: right;
    display: none;
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  nav ul {
    text-align: left;
    float: right;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 150px;
  }

  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #968a8a;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #968a8a;
  }

  nav ul li a {
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
  }

  nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: none;
  }

  .dropdown img {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-right: 4px;
  }

  ul .dditems {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #968a8a;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1094px) {
  .container {
    padding-left: 10px;
  }

  #brand {
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah simple as that - please accept the answer and feel free to ask any more question, happy to help

Comment: How can i add css transition effects to the dropdown like ths - http://www.alessioatzeni.com/wp-content/tutorials/html-css/CSS3-DropdownMenu/index.html